# TabNavigator covers content

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have this component that contains a list that is covered on the bottom side by the TabNavigator. Any ideas how to fix it? Is there only a styling way?

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container style={{ paddingBottom: 5 }}>
          <Header
            backgroundColor={'#1E6EC7'}
            placement="left"
            leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
            centerComponent={{ text: 'Programul Zilei', style: { color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 22 } }}
            rightComponent={<Icon name="ios-add" style={{ color: 'white' }} onPress={() => {
               const {students}=this.props;
               this.props.navigation.navigate('AddClass', {students})}} />}
          />
          <List>
            <FlatList
              data={this.props.classes}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${index}`}
              extraData={this.state}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                  <ListItem
                    leftIcon={<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}><Icon1 name="times" size={24} style={{ paddingRight: 10, color: 'red' }} onPress={() => {
                      this.setState({ currentStudent: wantedEmployee })
                      this.setState({ currentClass: item })
                      this.props.classDeleteModalShowUp();
                      }} />                   
                  }
            />
          </List>
        </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [hide the tab navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-tab-navigator-contains-a-stack-and-you-want-to-hide-the-tab-bar-on-specific-screens) for that specific screen setting 
`tabBarVisible` as false in `navigationOptions`.
But I think the issue is because of the header, you can try using the [react navigation header bar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#docsNav). 
Otherwise you could add to the container a `paddingBottom` of the same height as the header